# Lifetime of temporary objects

Tags: c++

I encountered the following code (roughly):

```
struct StringBuffer {
    StringBuffer(const char* string) {strcpy(m_buffer, string);}
    const char* c_str() const {return m_buffer;}
    char m_buffer[128];
};


std::string foobar() {
    const char* buffer = StringBuffer("Hello World").c_str();
    return std::string(buffer);
}
```

Am I correct in assuming that after the line:

```
    const char* buffer = StringBuffer("Hello World").c_str();
```

`buffer` is pointing to a pointer in a deconstructed `StringBuffer` object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question at the end, yes, `buffer` will be a stray pointer.

To answer the more general question about lifetime of temporary values, I suggest you read [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) which says:

> ... all temporaries are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created...

Which for your case means that once the assignment to `buffer` is done, the temporary object is destructed.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that a const reference can extend the lifetime of a temporary.

Comment: @Hurkyl Listed as an exception on the reference page I linked to.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of const reference extending the lifetime, good article about it here: http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/ as well

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

By convention, functions like std::string::c_str() aren't meant for caching because even if it pointed to a non-temporary object, it could be invalidated by a re-allocation of the string it points to.